# How can I use a custom template for a Grails Domain?

Tags: grails

In Grails when creating a domain class using "create-domain-class" command, it generates a domain using a standard template.  How can I override this template with my own?

I've tried putting a custom template "DomainClass.groovy" at /src/main/templates/scaffolding and /src/main/templates/artifacts but neither gets used.

I am using Grails 3.3.1.

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/3.3.x/grails-plugin-domain-class there is a plugin in grails-core that does this part. You could I suppose clone/fork it - make changes and implement the plugin as some new name locally - may need more tracing of how they have enabled it in the core - you may need to call different way

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just extending our custom plugin with a new script to render a domain class template and a domain class spec template.

```
description( "Creates a Grails domain" ) {
  usage "grails create-new-domain <<DOMAIN NAME>>"
  argument name:'Domain Class Name', description:"The name of the domain to create"
  flag name:'force', description:"Whether to overwrite existing files"
}

def domainClassName = args[0]
def model = model(domainClassName)
def overwrite = flag('force') ? true : false

render  template: template('artifacts/CustomDomainClass.groovy'), //--could not be "DomainClass.groovy" as Grails template would override
        destination: file("grails-app/domain/${model.packagePath}/${model.className}.groovy"),
        model: model,
        overwrite: overwrite


render  template: template('artifacts/CustomDomainClassSpec.groovy'),
        destination: file("src/test/groovy/${model.packagePath}/${model.className}Spec.groovy"),
        model: model,
        overwrite: overwrite
```